# Are questions on pedagogy on topic?

Tags: discussion

There is currently an [Educator](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23685/educators) proposal in Area 51 but it seems that a good portion of the work of many academics is teaching.

Is is appropriate to ask questions about pedagogy and student teaching/learning on this site?

Comment: One element of teaching is how to give a proper presentation. Elements of how to do so have previously also been discussed at TeX.SE.

Comment: Given the up votes to the question and eykanal's answer, should we edit the [on topic](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page to clarify that pedagogy is on topic. I bring this up given how quickly we migrated away http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5395/what-impact-does-syntax-highlighting-have-on-students-progress-in-learning-a-ne as "off-topic".

Comment: @DanielE.Shub - Great idea, and I just noticed that I have the ability to modify the FAQ myself. [I added a line to the FAQ](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), let me know what you think.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Good question, I would say that pedagogy questions relating to the following would be on-topic:

- curriculum development for university courses
- curriculum/textbook recommendations for university courses
- techniques for presentation of material in university courses
- graduate students asking whether a particular course would be helpful for their research
- graduate students suggesting which courses to take as electives to help further their research

On a similar vein, the following would be off-topic:

- anything related to non-university courses
- students asking for help with specific courses
- discipline issues

That's all I can think of, I'd love to see what others come up with.

Comment: That about sums my thoughts, too.

Comment: Why are discipline issues, as they arise in a college setting, off topic? EG: "I am teaching a 30 person calculus course, mostly freshman, which involves a lot of groupwork and discussion. I am glad that my students are eager to engage with each other, but I have trouble getting them to return attention to the board when I need to lecture again. How can I get them to make this transition more efficiently?" Seems on topic to me.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer - Without further context, that seems on-topic to me, but this comment thread is not the place for this discussion. Why don't you [make a new meta post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and include a link to any relevant question?